# Does the ratio of consecutive terms of every concatenation sequence grow without bound?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $b$ be a base, that is, an integer greater than or equal to $2$. The concatenation sequence associated with $b$, is the sequence of positive integers $s_n$ where the $n$-th term is the number $n...n$. That is, you write $n$ in base $b$, concatenate it with itself $n$ times, then write the resulting number in base $b$. My question is, does the ratio of consecutive terms $s_{n+1} / s_n$ of every concatenation sequence go to $\infty$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the ratio blows up for any $b\in\mathbb Z_{\geq2}$.

---

Proof sketch: Suppose $n$ and $n+1$ have the same number of digits in baes $b$, say $m$, then

\begin{align*}
\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}&=\frac{(n+1)\Big(1+b^m+b^{2m}+\cdots+b^{nm}\Big)}{n\Big(1+b^m+b^{2m}+\cdots+b^{m(n-1)}\Big)}\\[1em]
&=\frac{n+1}n\left(1+\frac{b^{mn}}{1+b^m+b^{2m}+\cdots+b^{m(n-1)}}\right)\\[1em]
&=\frac{n+1}n\cdot\frac{b^{mn}}{b^{mn}-1}\cdot{(b^m-1)}.
\end{align*}
As $n\to\infty$, we have $m\to\infty$ and therefore the ratio blows up.

---

In fact, even if the number of concatenations is fixed for all $n$, the ratio still blows up (this can be shown using the same idea as above and the fact $n+1$ has $1$ more digit in base $b$ than $n$ if $n=b^p$ for some $p\in\mathbb N$).